# Are non-Muslims living under Islamic rule allowed to make idols or possess crosses?

Tags: sharia, sunni, non-muslim

We know that as Muslims we are obliged to destroy idols and images. But are non-Muslims living under Islamic rule allowed to make idols and images as part of their worship? And what about crosses? Are Christians  living under Islamic rule allowed to possess crosses? We know that we are obliged to erase or cut crosses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Christians are allowed to make/possess crucifixes provided that they keep them inside their homes and churches and do not publicly display them in Muslim cities. The pact of Dhimma allows them to retain their religion and crosses are a part of their religion.

There is difference of opinion on whether idolators can be Dhimmis, but according to the madhabs which allow it, the ruling should be the same as that of crosses for Christians.

**Ref:**

> ولا يمكنون من التصليب على أبواب كنائسهم وظواهر حيطانها، ولا يتعرض لهم إذا نقشوا ذلك داخلها
>
> They will not be allowed to make crucifixes on the doors or the external walls of their churches, and if they make them indoors then they will not be interfered with.
>
> <sup>— [Ahkaam Ahl al-Dhimmah](https://shamela.ws/book/218/988#)</sup>

Comment: Just a little question related to this. If their religion obliges them to show a part of their religion in public what do we do? Does the ruling stay the same?